# My pod doesn't show a page in the Cocoapods website

Tags: cocoapods

I created a Cocoapod which can be accessed here:

https://cocoapods.org/pods/SFFontFeatures

This pod installs and works great in when linked to apps.

However, it doesn't show a page for my pod on the cocoapods.org website. When I go to the above URL, it redirects directly to my github page.

Just about every pod I see listed on the website has their own page. Is there a way to configure my pod so that I get a page on cocoapods.org?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known CocoaPods issue with the indexer. See https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/9116 and follow https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoapods.org/issues/424

Comment: Thank you Paul. I will follow the Cocoapods issues related to this.